# Why is my render() function getting called before my componentWillReceiveProps()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm looking at the documentation here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html and can't figure out why I'm having this problem.

My situation is that I have a component like

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
       super(props);

       this.state = { something: null };
    }

    render() 
    {
       // ... uses something
    } 

ProductSorter.propTypes =
{
   something: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

and my `render` function of course assumes that `something` is non-`null` since the property is required. However, it seems that `render` is still getting called before a prop for `something` has been received.

Furthermore, I'm using `MyComponent` like

```
{ valueIsNonNull && <MyComponent something={value} }
```

and still `render` is getting called before a `something` is even passed in.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If something is coming in as a prop, you access it  inside your component via  `this.props.something`

componentWillReceiveProps is Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not called for the initial render.

Answer (score 0):

Please consult https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

> // You can chain any of the above with `isRequired` to make sure a warning
>
> // is shown if the prop isn't provided.

So, the PropTypes will not cease it's `render()` functions although the programmer did not supply the `required props` it will only shows *warnings* at your console

if you wanted to check for that prop, add this to your render

```
render () {
    if(typeof this.props.SomeRequiredProp === 'undefined') return null
    
    {/*the following will renders when the required prop is supplied*/}
    <div>Rendered! {this.props.SomeRequiredProp}</div>
}
```